# How to add multiple statements inside a when statement in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to have multiple statements for one condition. For example: this is a sample code for when statement.

```
when (x) {
    1 -> print("x == 1")
    2 -> print("x == 2")
     else -> { // Note the block
        print("x is neither 1 nor 2")
   }
}
```

When x is 1, I also want to have an extra statement like x += 10, how can I do it?

Answer (score 45):

You have the solution in your question with the "Note the block" comment. Branches of `when` can be blocks that can contain any number of statements:

```
when(x) {
    1 -> {
        println("x == 1")
        x += 10
        println("x == 11")
    }
    2 -> { ... }
    else -> { ... }
}
```

Writing a single statement branch just has a simplified syntax so that you don't need to surround it with `{}`.

Comment: That's a bit weird. Everywhere else in the language, adding braces means it's a lambda. How would you make a when-expression that returns a lambda of type `() -> Unit`?

Comment: Hmm, that's a rather interesting question. You can do `-> { { println("hello") } }`, for example. The lambda is the last statement in the branch, and will be returned. You could also do `-> fun() { println("hello") }`, that might be more legible.

Comment: The nicest way IMO is `-> ({})`. And I totally agree it is weird

Comment: Ah, that is pretty neat, actually.